# Python: Is it possible to judge input using if statement in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I'm using python 3.6. I want to input a string or something and judge it by if statement in one line.
This might be a simple question but I couldn't solve this problem. I know how to do in without one line:

```
words = input()
if words == 'a':
    print(words)
else:
    print('Not a')
```

However, I couldn't put it into one line. What I want to do is like this:

```
print(input() if input() == 'a' else 'Not a')
```

It doesn't work. The first input and the second input is different. Is it possible to keep the result of first input and check its condition in one line?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the singleton generator/list trick to avoid calling a function twice, but still reuse its result:

```
print(next(x if x == 'a' else 'Not a' for x in [input()]))
```

While you're at it, you can also shorten the ternary `x if y else z` construct to become even more cryptic :-)

```
print(next(('Not a', x)[x == 'a'] for x in [input()]))
```

But fewer lines are **not** an end in itself. The five lines you have are perfectly valid and **readable**.

Comment: Note to the OP : please pay special attention to the last line => __fewer lines are not an end in itself. The five lines you have are perfectly valid and readable__ - this cannot be stressed enough.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind carefully :). I just got interested in how one line works. This answered my question perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> words = input()
'a'
>>> print(words if words=='a' else 'not a')
a
>>> words = input()
'b'
>>> print(words if words=='a' else 'not a')
not a
```

Comment: "Is it possible to keep the result of first input and check its condition **in one line**?"

Comment: ah yes, didn't notice that